# jQuery UI tabs - page goes down when the URL is redirected to a particular tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an issue with the jQuery UI tabs. When I want to make a redirection to particular tab, it loads the page but not from the beginning of the page, it opens up the page from the middle.

```
Eg: http://loacalhost/art-space#tabs-4
//This loads the particular tab but from the middle of the page
```

I need to rectify this. Please tell me if you need more details, Is there are a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just scroll to the top if there is a hash just after the dom loads.

Try:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (location.hash) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }, 1);
});
```

In the page you are redirecting to.